# End to end test of web API project and Azure Function project

Tags: c#, azure-functions, integration-testing, xunit, webapi

I a Visual Studio solution that consists of a web api project and an azure functions project. The web api places address information on a queue, and an azure queue trigger picks up the message from the queue, validates the address using the USPS address service and then saves the address to a SQL Lite database if it's valid. The project uses development storage. In order to get it to work, I have to run both as start up  projects.

I have written controller tests before using the AspNet testhost. What I want to do is write an end to end test. Use test host to post to the web API, wait 3 seconds and query the SQL Server instance to assert that the address was saved to the database (or not saved if it was invalid.)

I'm not sure how to get the function app to run in this scenario. Any ideas on how I can start the functions project from the controller tests? Both are in the same Visual Studios project. Or is my approach all wrong?

Comment: I don't think you can. You just need to make the function project one of the startup projects again. Either that or create an instance of it in Azure against which to run your tests

Comment: I'll have to try that. I thought I would somehow need to start the functions project. This is for an employment test, they don't want anything deployed. Also I would then need to set up an Azure DB. I'm all out of free credits.